# Num Pad input for Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am using a num pad with pygame and the num pad does not get recognized.

I know that I have to use the code below, but not how:

```
if (event.key >= 0x100 and event.key <= 0x109)
```

Here is my code to use the <kbd>return</kbd> key:

```
if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key != 300:
        if (event.key >= 0x100 and event.key <= 0x109 and event.key == pygame.K_RETURN):
....
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you want to check if a key of the keypad was pressed, you can use the following [constants](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html);

```
K_KP0                 keypad 0
K_KP1                 keypad 1
K_KP2                 keypad 2
K_KP3                 keypad 3
K_KP4                 keypad 4
K_KP5                 keypad 5
K_KP6                 keypad 6
K_KP7                 keypad 7
K_KP8                 keypad 8
K_KP9                 keypad 9
K_KP_PERIOD   .       keypad period
K_KP_DIVIDE   /       keypad divide
K_KP_MULTIPLY *       keypad multiply
K_KP_MINUS    -       keypad minus
K_KP_PLUS     +       keypad plus
K_KP_ENTER    \r      keypad enter
K_KP_EQUALS   =       keypad equals
```

You would use `event.key >= 0x100 and event.key <= 0x109` to check for `K_KP0`, `K_KP1`, ... `K_KP9`, because `K_KP0` is `256` in decimal and `0x100` in hex, `K_KP9` is `265` in decimal and `0x109` in hex etc.

Also, it would be better for readability to actually use the constants instead of the hex literals.

Here's a simple example on how to check for a all key pad numbers or the key pad return key:

```
import pygame

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))

while True:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()
        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if pygame.K_KP0 <= e.key <= pygame.K_KP9:
                print('Numpad 0-9')
            if e.key == pygame.K_KP_ENTER:
                print('Numpad ENTER')
```

Your code

```
 if (event.key >= 0x100 and event.key <= 0x109 and event.key == pygame.K_RETURN):
```

will not work because `event.key` can't be greater than `256`, smaller than `265` and equal to `13` at the same time (`K_RETURN` is `13`).

Comment: Checking for the actual numeric value range defeats the whole point of using symbolic constants...so I don't think that is good advice.

Comment: @martineau It's not my advise but of course I agree with you; that's totally right. I updated my answer.

Comment: Checking `e.key >= pygame.K_KP0 and e.key <= pygame.K_KP9` isn't really much better.

Comment: @sloth: It works well. I would like to ask: `K_KP_ENTER ` works for enter button on a num pad and `K_RETURN` for the enter button on a long keyboard. Is there an explanation for it?

Comment: @ddd The simple answer is just that your keyboard sends different signals to your computer if you press the regular enter key or the numpad enter key.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best approach would be to create `set` composed of the keyboard constants and check for membership in it. Membership testing for inclusion in a `set` is *very* fast in Python, **plus** creating it by using only the symbolic constants already defined by `pygame` makes your own code completely independent of their actual values.

Something like this:

```
from pygame.locals import *

NUMPAD_KEYS = {K_KP0, K_KP1, K_KP2, K_KP3, K_KP4, K_KP5, K_KP6, K_KP7, K_KP8, K_KP9}

if event.key in NUMPAD_KEYS:
    # Do something...
```

Comment: I don't think you win anything by using a set. It's no accident the constants are ordered. It's like saying you should use the regex `[a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j]` instead of simply `[a-j]`.

Comment: @sloth: You're missing the main point, which isn't just that membership testing in them is fast—although that's nice—it's that using them allows you to write code that is independent of the actual numeric values or their relationship to one another (such as whether one is larger or small than another).

Comment: I get your point. First, to note even a slight difference between `x in {...}` and `a < x < b`, you'll have to call the code 10000000 times, so that's clearly not an issue. You could probably gain more performance by caching attribute lookups and putting your code into a function to minimize global lookups.

Comment: Second, I would agree if we were talking about arbitrary variables in an arbitrary context, but in this case, the relationship between the constants is reasonable and obvious (`0` before `1` before `2`, `a` before `b` before `c`), and will never ever spontaneously change. I just don't see any value in being independent from the fact that `K_a`  is smaller than `K_b`, because it's well defined. And by using something `K_a < event.key < K_z` you're also not dependent of the actual numeric value.

Comment: @sloth: Using using something like `K_a < event.key < K_z` assumes that `K_a` is less that `K_z`. I also think your down-vote is completely unjustified (and likely just revengeful rather than logical). Grow up!

Comment: @martineauI I disagree with you on this topic but I don't think your answer deserves a downvote; I didn't downvote your answer.

Comment: @sloth: My apologies for the accusation. Guess we can agree to disagree...although it does illustrate why one shouldn't make assumptions.